# How to catch bash script error, which is run through a python script?

Tags: python, bash, airflow

I'm using Airflow and i have some python scripts, one of it launch sh script (1 or many). For airflow even if this bash script return an error, it considers that the task is success.

I would like to return the bash error in my python script as airflow will notice.

```
import glob
import os
from os import path
import subprocess

odsPath = '/apps/data/02_OS/'


for odsFolder in os.listdir(odsPath):
    if(odsFolder in fileNames):
        newPath = odsPath+odsFolder
        print('Script path: ', newPath)
        for foldFiles in os.listdir(newPath):
            if(foldFiles.endswith('sh')):
                print('Sh script can be launch: ', foldFiles)
            if(foldFiles.startswith('run') and foldFiles.endswith('.sh')):
                os.system('sh ' + newPath+'/'+foldFiles)
                print('Script: '+foldFiles+' executed')
```

In this case, there are bash errors, like this for example '**Number of parameters is incorrect**'

Thanks for help :)

Comment: What have you tried? You want to capture the 'STDERR' output (or maybe 'STDOUT' too if the scripts are naughty and use the wrong output stream)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.system()` runs a command completely outside of Python's control, though you can examine its return code and `raise`  an error if there is a failure. As suggested in the `os.system` documentation, a better approach which gives you more control and fewer moving parts is `subprocess`:

```py
subprocess.run(['sh', os.path.join(newPath,foldFiles)],
    check=True)
```

The `check=True` causes a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` to be raised if the subprocess fails. See further [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)